# TextFields in ScrollView not responding in ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a screen like this

[image: ViewController]

Here i have two subview one is container and another one is scrollview.

I added textfields and other elements in scrollview using UIView

All textfields are responding except SBP and DBP textfields. I connected these to inerface builder. This is only happens in iphone 4s but its working perfectly in other devices.

Why it should happen.? Can any one tell me how to solve this.?

Comment: Check with the bounds of the textFields for the particular 4s Device

Comment: I think view size is not enough. Try to match the view size and textfield view frames correctly

Comment: I set the view size is same as scrollview size i.e., width 600, height 450 using Auto Layout Constraints Tendulkar